# index out of bound by click

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I need to get the last edited cell's row index of a `datagridview` with the `cellClick_event`.

I tried like this:

```
    private void DataGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        var lastIndex = DataGridView.SelectedRows[DataGridView.SelectedRows.Count - 1].Index;
        var currentIndex = DataGridView.CurrentRow.Index;
        if (currentIndex != lastIndex)
        {
            //code
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
```

but it's not working. I'm getting error:

```
index out of bound
```

- How to get the last edited `cell's` row index of a datagridview with the `cellClick_event`?
- Is there any other event other than `datagridview.cellclick` to solve it?

Comment: You want the Row that was last edited? as in the row that is/was last selected.

Comment: No. I need the current modified row. didn't find anything in datagridview events.

Comment: I don't think the index would be same, you should be checking if the `CurrentRow` is already part of the collection or not something like `.SelectedRows.Contains(DataGridView.CurrentRow)` (but this is rows selected by user and not necessarily edited)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to compare the row clicked with the row currently beeing edited, this should do the trick;

```
void DataGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {

    int currentIndex = DataGridView.CurrentRow.Index;
    int clickedCellRowIndex = e.RowIndex;

    if (currentIndex == clickedCellRowIndex) {
        //do work
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the datagridview editeMode to EditonEnter. Then when you click in the cell, it should give you the index of the last modified row, which is the row index of the cell you have enetered.

```
int i = dataGridView.CurrentRow.Index;
```

Or, If your after the index of the previous row edited, you could record the above value in the "Cell_Leave" event handle.

Comment: That's what I did.. it gives me the current row index. I need the index of the last edited row.

Comment: If you want it to give you the row index as you edit the cell, see my update.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use the CellEndEdit event. When this is called then you will have access to the row that has just been edited. However you will have to find a way to see if it has actually been edited, as I think this is called even if the edit is cancelled.

B

Answer (score 0):

It might help you this

```
   private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
    }
```